# Pandas GroupBy- Remove groups with less than 2 items

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got a Pandas DataFrame of ID's which I've grouped by 5 columns.

Looking to obtain an output of groups containing only 2 or more IDs. Or at the very least, sort by number of IDs (descending).

```
for key, item in grouped:

    print(key)
    print(item['ID'])
    print()
```

Got the above to achieve a long list of keys and their IDs, wondering if I need to incorporate some sort of size() command in there to achieve the desired output?

Looking for an output like this:

```
('Met', 59.0, 0.0, 0.0, 196.0, 66.0)
702     510000261554
1184    510000247456
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Quite new to coding so would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey, can you provide an example of your starting and grouped DataFrame?

Comment: @Fred Annoyingly, it's sensitive data so I can't really go into much more detail. My starting DataFrame was quite a simple table of Component ID's, their dimensions and their material. I then grouped these Component ID's on the dimensions and material and the idea was to obtain IDs which are essentially the same component. I actually couldn't manage to get the grouped DataFrame to print, I had to use the "For key, item in grouped" loop above to get any output. Before that, I got this: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000023032788B88>

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can understand, you have a dataset looking like:

```
print(df)

| id | length | width | material | ... |
+----+--------+-------+----------+-----+
| 1  | 100    | 50    | plastic  | ... |
| 1  | 100    | 50    | plastic  | ... |
| 2  | 100    | 50    | wood     | ... |
| 2  | 100    | 100   | wood     | ... |
```

You then group by `id, length, width, material`?

If you then apply `.size()` this will return a Series with a multi index. You can then filter this Series to rows where the size is greater than 1.

```
# Group the data

s = df.groupby(["id", "length", "width", "material"]).size()

print(s)

| (id, length, width, material) |   |
+-------------------------------+---+
| (1, 100, 50, plastic)         | 2 |
| (2, 100, 50, wood)            | 1 |
| (2, 100, 100, wood)           | 1 |



# Get all groups with more than 1 row

more_than_1_row = s[s>1]

print(more_than_1_row)

| (id, length, width, material) |   |
+-------------------------------+---+
| (1, 100, 50, plastic)         | 2 |


# Convert the Series to a DataFrame

df_more_than_1_row = more_than_1_row.reset_index()

print(df_more_than_1_row)

| id | length | width | material |   |
+----+--------+-------+----------+---+
| 1  | 100    | 50    | plastic  | 2 |
```

This final table has all the information you need in it's index, if you'd like, you can `.reset_index()` on the final Series to produce a DataFrame with the 5 columns: id, length, width, material and a final column containing the number of duplicates.

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out! This is very close to what I need however I am not grouping on ID (this is a unique number not just 1, 2, 3 etc) I am only grouping on Material, Length and Width. Therefore I need the output to return which ID's fall into that Material, Length & Width. I need to almost filter my output in my original question to "more than one row" like you have done above.